# Snowflake : Load JSON with null values using empty string

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I want to load empty strings in JSON as null value into snowflake table.

The [snowflake document](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/sql/create-file-format.html) says that this should be possible with NULL_IF=('')

I tried that in COPY INTO statement, but did not work as expected.

Here is my sample JSON:

```
  {
    "Id": 100,
    "Address": ""
  }
```

Here is my sample query:

```
COPY INTO my_table FROM 's3://my_bucket/' 
FILES = ('my_file.json') 
FILE_FORMAT = (TYPE = json STRIP_OUTER_ARRAY = true NULL_IF = ('\\N', 'NULL', 'null', 'NUL', ''))
CREDENTIALS = (AWS_KEY_ID = 'my_key' AWS_SECRET_KEY = 'my_secret_key') 
MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME = CASE_SENSITIVE 
ON_ERROR = 'CONTINUE' 
FORCE = TRUE ;
```

Comment: What result did you see and what was your table definition? Your example worked for me when I set MATCH_BY_COLUMN_NAME = CASE_INSENSITIVE using the sample JSON (otherwise I ended up with nulls in both columns).

Comment: @MikeDonovan My table definition is something like this : `create or replace TABLE myTable ( "Id" VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL, "Address" VARCHAR(255), "Number1" NUMBER(11,6), "Date1" TIMESTAMP_LTZ(9), constraint myTablePK primary key ("Id") );` The result I got from both CASE_INSENSITIVE and CASE_SENSITIVE : _Failed to cast variant value "" to FIXED_. If try `SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE "Address" IS NULL`, nothing will return, because it is loaded as empty spaces.